# Would installing MacOS on a new partition fix my partition table?

Tags: install

I think I messed up my partition table, would installing mac os on a new partition (to keep the old one which I WANT to use) fix that so when I boot the `Option` key works and everything runs smoothly?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the answer is yes. I have successufly reinstalled mac os without any loss to my data. and it has restored my recover partition and boot